# Text Substitutions in ACE Editor

Tags: javascript, codemirror, ace-editor

Codemirror allows for text substitutions via `doc.markText(...)`. (i.e. it is possible to substitute a part of the document by arbitrary HTML). This is really handy when you want to support languages with special characters that can be abbreviated. (e.g. `-->` for implication arrow or `/\` for a logical and). Especially helpful is the fact that only the visualization is changed and not the document itself.

My question: Is there a similar functionality in ACE which I am missing or is there an extension?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported yet, but ace foldlwidgets are somewhat similar, and can be modified to work for this use case. I think you should open an issue on ace bug tracker about this.